# Migration wicket 8.* from 7.*, problem with onRequestHandlerResolved() method on AbstractRequestCycleListener

Tags: wicket

I'm working on Wicket 8.* migration when I struggle on onRequestHandlerResolved() under IRequestCycleListener method conversion.

As per my structure of logic in my code wicket 7.15.0

```
public class MyRequestCycleListener extends AbstractRequestCycleListener{
//All methods override here
    @Override
    public void onRequestHandlerResolved(RequestCycle cycle, IRequestHandler handler) {
       if (handler instanceof ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler) {
           ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler requestHandler = (ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler) handler;
           if (requestHandler.getListenerInterface().getListenerInterfaceClass().isAssignableFrom(         IFormSubmitListener.class)) {
                 //here made some login as well as every onSubmit
           }
       }
    }
}
```

As wicket 8.* changes
AbstractRequestCycleListener class converts to IRequestCycleListener interface
ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler renamed to ListenerRequestHandler
Deprecates RequestListenerInterface and also IFormSubmitListener makes error

How to convert code to migration on wicket 8.9.0 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
public class MyRequestCycleListener implements IRequestCycleListener{

    @Override
    public void onRequestHandlerResolved(RequestCycle cycle, IRequestHandler handler) {
        if (handler instanceof ListenerRequestHandler) {
             ListenerRequestHandler requestHandler = (ListenerRequestHandler) handler;

            if (requestHandler.getComponent() instanceof Form) {
                  //here made some login as well as every onSubmit
                  Form form = (Form) requestHandler.getComponent();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: requestHandler.getComponent().isAssignableFrom(Form.class) is not possible. requestHandler.getComponent().getClass().isAssignableFrom(Form.class) is correctly accepted in wicket 8. And my one double, could you once conform use requestHandler.getClass().isAssignableFrom(Form.class) ?